# How does argv work in this execvp call?

Tags: c

I'm studying Unix system calls (`execvp`) and was confused by this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        perror("little arguments");
        return -1;
    }
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: why is `execvp`’s second argument `&argv[1]`? From what I know about execvp, the second argument should be an array of commands (`ls` `-l`, for example) and I don’t think `&argv[1]` is an array of commands. It’s just the address of a string, right? But this code runs perfectly with any command (e.g. as `./a.out ls`, `./a.out ls -l`, …).

Comment: `&argv[1]` is `argv + 1`, i.e. the part of the array of strings `argv` after the first element.

Comment: Take a look at the declaration `int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);`. The first argument is the *file being executed* (e.g. `ls` in `argv[1]`). The second argument is an *array of pointers to char* (must be `NULL` terminated). `argv + 1` is just a pointer to the `argv` array beginning at ***the address of*** `argv[1]` (which would be `"ls"` (again), then `"opt"` (in `argv[2]`), then `"dir"` (in `argv[3]`), then the `NULL` (that always ends `argv`). So it is just a shorthand to use `argv` beginning at `1` for the array of pointers required by `execvp`.

Comment: In other words, using `&argv[1]` creates a `char *const argv[]` beginning at the address of `argv[1]`. So the pointers in the array would point to `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, `argv[3]`, `...`.

Comment: The use of `perror()` when no system call has failed is a bad idea. You’ll probably be told `little arguments: no error` which isn’t what you mean.  Use `fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s command [argument ...]\n”, argv[0]);` or something very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from both my comments above:

> It’s just the address of a string, right?

Right. The *address of* (e.g. a *pointer to*) a string. `execvp` requires a `char *const argv[]` as the second argument. (*an array of const pointer to char*). `&argv[1]` simply provides the starting address for the *array of const pointers to char*.

Since you have an array of pointers to char, a simple way to visualize what is happening is simply to `printf` what each pointer (each string) in the array. You can iterate by indexes, or declare a *pointer to the first pointer* and iterate over each of the pointers by simply using *pointer arithmetic*.

A quick example is simply to add a quick `char **p = &argv[1];` to your code and then iterate over the pointers that will be passed to `execvp` (up to the ending `NULL`) to see what is being passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        perror("little arguments");
        return -1;
    }
    int n = 1;              /* declare a counter variable */
    char **p = &argv[n];    /* declare a pointer to pointer to argv[1] */
    while (*p)              /* iterate over each pointer, and index */
        printf ("points to argv[%d]: '%s'\n", n++, *p++);
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/execvp ls -l dat
points to argv[1]: 'ls'
points to argv[2]: '-l'
points to argv[3]: 'dat'
total 892
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    31 May  6  2016 11nums.txt
...
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions of either the comments or the answer.